# Fetch Data and turn data into CSV and download

Tags: javascript, csv, download, fetch

I have an endpoint I fetch that returns a CSV. I'm trying to export that string as a CSV file on click. The header in the response contains content-dispostion and its content type is 'text/csv'.

How can I do this?

```js
let download = await function(){
  let response = await fetch('www.endpointblahblah.com')
  
  //The rest of the function needs to take the string that's returned from the response and export as a CSV file by downloading it.
}
```

Turning the response into JSON throws an error. It should absolutely do this because a JSON object is not returned, it is text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you specify what error exactly?

Comment: I may have found my answer. I didn't realize I could just turn that string into text with .text().